# "Haven't we wasted our time, we'd be in better shape today"

Tags: grammar, conditionals

Is the above sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: It's *syntactically* sound, but it doesn't make sense. (Well, it does, but it's extremely awkward.) Barring some specific area of concern, it would more naturally be expressed as: ***If we hadn't*** *wasted our time, we'd be in better shape today.*

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, your sentence is not correct because "haven't we" is a question form and you are making a statement. I believe that what you are trying to say is "Had we not wasted our time we'd be in better shape shape today" or, in a less old fashioned form "If we had not wasted our time ...". A sentence starting "haven't we" would be "Haven't we wasted our time? We would be in better shape today if we'd got on with the important job." Do you see the difference?

Comment: It should have been "Had we not wasted our time, we'd be in better shape today."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example that covers three different points of English grammar which we need to look at separately.

First, to look at the tenses, consider a different sentence that avoids the second and third issues:

> If we have not wasted our time we would be in better shape today.

*Have* implies something that could potentially occur at any time up to the present and so can only affect things in the future. Thus we can say

> If we have not wasted our time we will be in better shape tomorrow.

or

> If we had not wasted our time we would be in better shape today.

So the tenses are syntactically correct but not semantically correct.

Next comes the replacement of the *if* clause with inversion:

> Had we not wasted our time we would be in better shape today.

This is perfectly standard but opinions will differ as to which is better or more common in any given register, dialect or time period.

Thirdly there is the question of whether we can contract when this requires a change of word order:

> Had we not  - > hadn't we

This is perfectly standard by itself (for example, in a question) but combined with the less common example of inversion you end up with a very strange-sounding, if perfectly correct, sentence. Since it is a principle of good English that you should not require the reader to do mental gymnastics to work out what you mean I would stick with

> Had we not wasted our time we would be in better shape today.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, the first part is phrased as a question "*Haven't we wasted our time?*" Which might well be said with an air of disappointment or regret.
I'm guessing what you are trying to say is

> "*If we hadn't wasted our time, we'd be in better shape today*"

Comment: Or as @BoldBen puts it "Had we not wasted our time, we would be in better shape today", which I do not consider in the least "old fashioned", though if it was it would see that as an added incentive to use it.

Comment: @WS2: I think [the tide of linguistic history](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Had+I+not+seen%2CIf+I+hadn%27t+seen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHad%20I%20not%20seen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIf%20I%20had%20not%20seen%3B%2Cc0) is against you on that one! The "inverted" form was actually more common a century and a half ago, but the explicitly hypothetical ***if*** form is about three times *more* common today. And that's in primarily *written* contexts. In spoken contexts I think the shift in preference would be even more pronounced.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know someone, a solicitor by profession, who belongs to an organisation which arranges week-ends, for groups, in historic houses. The only rule is that the guests address one another in seventeenth-century English. So she spends a lot of time mugging up on the Authorised Version of the Bible, and Shakespeare.  Everyone to their own taste, I suppose. (Perhaps she thinks she can impress a magistrates bench with the odd Shakesperian turn of phrase.)  I'm not quite that mad, but the fact that someone declares something "obsolete" is even more incentive for me to use it.

Comment: @WS2 I didn't say I didn't like it or, to some extent, regret the passing of proper English (I use "fewer" when appropriate and avoid the verb "to leverage" like the plague). I merely wanted to warn the OP that the correct form might mark one out as a non-ideomatic speaker.

Comment: @WS2: I had a penfriend as a teenager, and we were both into calligraphy. Our weekly "epistles" (musings about philosophy / religion) were mostly Medieval English laboriously written in copperplate, so I got lots of practice in "old-fashioned" orthography, vocabulary, and syntax! But I'd like to think I was pretty fluent in "Standard English" even at the time. I don't think it's all that wise for people who *don't* already have that fluency to be distracted by outdated usages that no longer sit naturally in most modern registers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am sure you are right. But I do love to hear people (Indians especially) use outdated but elegant English forms of an earlier generation.

Comment: @WS2: Indeed. I wouldn't want to be patronising, but I do sometimes find it "charming" to hear IE speakers quite naturally using outdated Victorian syntax & vocabulary.